# Fatal error: Call to a member function make_calendar() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, web, wamp

I am new to PHP and trying to build a calendar booking sytem.
I am getting

> > Fatal error: Call to a member function make_calendar() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\calendar\calendar.php on line 46

and

> > Notice: Undefined variable: calendar in C:\wamp\www\calendar\calendar.php on line 46

error while accessing my website at localhost/calendar/calendar.php

```
                                      // calendar.php
    <?
    include('php/connect.php'); 
    include('classes/class_calendar.php');
    $calendar = new booking_diary($link);
    // some more code
    ?>
```

//  some HTML code in between

```
<?php     

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $calendar->after_post($month, $day, $year);  
}   

// Call calendar function
//Error on this line
$calendar->make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year);

?>
```

And the class 'booking_diary' inside class_calendar.php looks like

```
class booking_diary {

        function __construct($link) {
        $this->link = $link;    
        }
function make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month,year){

  // Add a value to these public variables  
  $this->day = $day;    
  $this->month = $month;
  $this->year = $year;

  $this->selected_date = $selected_date;    
  $this->first_day = $first_day;

  $this->back = $back;
  $this->back_month = date("m", $back);
  $this->back_year = date("Y", $back); // Minus one month back arrow

  $this->forward = $forward;
  $this->forward_month = date("m", $forward);
  $this->forward_year = date("Y", $forward); // Add one month forward arrow    

  // Make the booking array
  $this->make_booking_array($year, $month);

  }

// some more PHP code
}
```

Where `$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);` inside **connect.php**

Error is on line

```
$calendar->make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year);
```

Comment: Dont try to duplicate your questions as you have posted the same before sometime..

Comment: But I havent got answer to my problem

Comment: Then try to edit and improve your question. Dont try to post it again.

Comment: I wish I could have got an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your gonna kick yourself !!!

This could be one of your problems:

The year parameter does not have a `$` sign in front of it, when you declare the method in your class code.

```
function make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month,year){
```

try

```
function make_calendar($selected_date, $first_day, $back, $forward, $day, $month, $year){
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after lots of struggle.

I am using **wamp server 2.4** and enabling the **short open tag** solved my problem.

the code inside

was not actually being executed.